# Java Guessing Number Game(Not with Scanner)

Tags: java, server, client

So it's like a basic Server/client game but the numbers must be generated by the client and also  The client must make logical guesses, for example, if the server says ”Enter a smaller number” to 5 and ”Enter a greater number” to 0, the client’s guess must be between 0 and 5. How can I do this part?

Comment: Pl see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Welcome. Your question is very broad for Stack Overflow. The fact that you get answers that are not on the spot for your real problem is also a sign of this. Stack Overflow is much better suited for much more specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is a server/client implementation, then you should study a little bit about sockets:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: My problem is about generating numbers logically, i mean the client must remember the old numbers it guessed and guess a new number accordingly to the old numbers

Answer (score 0):

If it's the client "guessing" part you're struggling with, the simplest implementation is to simply keep taking halfway between the smallest number you no to be "too high" and the largest number you know to be "too low", something like:

```
public class NumberGuessingClientExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NumberGuessingClient(new ServerStub()).findNumber();
}

public static class NumberGuessingClient {
    private int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private final NumberGuessingServer server;

    public NumberGuessingClient(NumberGuessingServer server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public int findNumber() {
        Result result = null;
        int value = nextGuess();
        while ((result = server.makeGuess(value)) != Result.CORRECT) {
            System.out.println(value + " = " + result);
            if (result == Result.TOO_HIGH) {
                max = value - 1;
            } else if (result == Result.TOO_LOW) {
                min = value + 1;
            }
            value = nextGuess();
        }
        System.out.println(value);
        return value;
    }

    private int nextGuess() {
        return (int) ((((long) max - (long) min) / 2) + min);
    }
}

public interface NumberGuessingServer {
    Result makeGuess(int value);
}

public static class ServerStub implements NumberGuessingServer {

    private static final int RESULT = 3;

    public Result makeGuess(int value) {
        if (value > RESULT) {
            return Result.TOO_HIGH;
        }
        if (value < RESULT) {
            return Result.TOO_LOW;
        }
        return Result.CORRECT;
    }

}

public enum Result {
    CORRECT, TOO_HIGH, TOO_LOW
}
```

}